# Share part of android section between multiple `build.gradle.kts` files

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to share some parts of `build.grade.kts` between android project.

For the moment, I have a library and an application, which have the same `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes` declaration. Later, I will have other applications with same configuration too.

How to share part of this configuration? I made research about that, found post telling to use apply from, but I have error when I have a `android` section outside the main build.gradle.kts.

Idealy, I hope to find a very small github project (or all *.gradle.kts files) that I can re-use and modify to integrate in my project.
Here a sample `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.company.product"
    compileSdk = 33
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
    
    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            keyAlias = "release"
            keyPassword = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
            storeFile = file("....")
            storePassword = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.company.product"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = computedVersionCode
        versionName = getVersionName(computedVersionCode)
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dbg"
            versionNameSuffix = "-debug"
            ndk {
                abiFilters += listOf("x86_64", "arm64-v8a")
            }
        }
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix = ""
            versionNameSuffix = ""
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            ndk {
                abiFilters += listOf("x86_64", "arm64-v8a")
            }
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments += "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.1")
}
```

And quite the same for my library:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
}

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Ideally, I would like to shared sections `signingConfigs` or `buildTypes` between these both build gradle DSL scripts.